# Objective C and Swift

Tags: objective-c, scope, singleton, swift

I am trying to switch one of my apps from Objective-C to swift. There are some things in swift language that I can't get to work. First of all, I have a `Model` class which I initialise in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I declare the `Model`'s object in the `.h` file in Objective-C like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)Model *model;
```

The in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I initialise it:

```
self.model=[[Model alloc]init];
```

And then I have the following method:

```
+(Model *)getCurrentModel{        
    AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;        
    return appdelegate.model;        
}
```

And then I can access the current instance of `Model` from any class by calling:

```
model = [AppDelegate getCurrentModel];
```

So, the first question, how can I do the same in Swift? Especially the static functions(the function that begin with `+`). I tried this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var model : Model?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        model = Model()
        return true
    }

class var currentModel : Model {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : Model = AppDelegate.sharedApplication.delegate //error AppDelegate.Type does not have a member named sharedApplication
        }
        return Static.instance.model
    }
```

Second question. In Objective C, we can make an instance variable and global variable and global function by declaring in`.h` file like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    //Instance Variables
    NSString *aName;
}
//Properties or variables that can be accessed globally
NSString *anotherName;

//Methods that have global scope
- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

Those functions that are not declared in the `.h` file have a local scope. How do I do the same in Swift?

Comment: Use ```static``` keyword to declare class functions. There is no concept of access modifiers in Swift(atleast for now). Everything you declare is public.

Comment: What about the error I got? sharedApplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sharedApplication` is a method of `UIApplication`, not of `AppDelegate`.
In addition, you have to unwrap the optional for then return value:

```
class var currentModel : Model {
    struct Static {
        static let instance  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    }
    return Static.instance.model!
}
```

Comment: Yeah, got it, thanks. Actually I was editing throughout to find a solution and forgot to change that. Just noticed it now.